# Emitting Main to Main event from electron menu

Tags: electron

I have a listener for 'select-current-project' in my Main process. It works fine when triggered from the renderer process, but how can I emit the same event from the Menu?

#### Menu is created in default `createWindow()`

```
var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
        label: 'Menu',
        submenu: [
            {
                label:'Open',
                click() {
                    // neither of these works
                    // app.emit('select-current-project')
                    // ipcRenderer.send('select-current-project')

                },
                accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+O'
            },
            {
                label:'Exit',
                click() { 
                    app.quit() 
                }
            },                
        ]
    }
])
```

#### My event handler

```
ipcMain.on('select-current-project', async (event, arg) => {
    // code
})
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure I understand the issue you are describing – but here is what I do:

The function `showProjectPicker` exists in `main.js` and is called by a menu action as shown below. If I want to call it from the `renderer` process I send a message over IPC.

```
{
  label: 'File',
  submenu: [
      { label: 'Open Project...', click: () => { showProjectPicker(); }, accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+o' }
    ]
}
```